# How to enter the dependant variables of Repeated Measures in Multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, repeated-measures

My study is to investigate the effect of energy density (ED) and portion size (PS) on the intake of food among 12 - 16 years old female students. There are two levels of ED (High and Low) and PS (Large and reference) is manipulated in the provided test meals for lunch.

My respondents had gone through four trials : (High ED, Large portion), (High ED, Reference portion), (Low ED, Large portion) and (Low ED, Reference portion).

If I want to use Multiple Regression, how can I enter 4 different dependent variables in the analysis of a meal - eg: test meal?

Should I compute the average for each condition or average of the intake of the dependent variable across the conditions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should organize your data in the ["long" format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data). 
If you do so, you will end up with a single dependent variable and two independent ones, one for each effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this is answer is correct, consider it marking as such (clicking the tick on the left side)